# (Java) GUI NumberFormatException catches exception, but hangs the window

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, try-catch, numberformatexception

Very new to GUI. Trying to make my code catch exceptions when a user leaves the textfield blank, or when the user doesn't enter an integer. When I used InputMismatchException, the GUI window would keep working but I would have tons of errors on the output window on NetBeans.

When I switched the catch block to NumberFormationException, there is nothing on the output window, but the GUI window stops working, as I cannot enter anything, change anything or even close the window without force stopping the run.

Works fine when an integer is put in, but anything else hangs the problem.

The code that contains the try-catch block is:

```
private void createAnswerField()
{
    answerField = new JTextField(5);

    answerField.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
}

/**
 * When the user presses enter in the text field, this is the class that makes the rest happen
 */
class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        boolean correctInput = false;

        while(!correctInput)
        {
            try
            {   
                userInput = Integer.parseInt(answerField.getText());
                correctInput = true;

                if (userInput == getCorrectAnswer())
                {
                    if (counter > 1) //Fixes the try/tries problem
                    {
                        answerLabel.setText("Yay! It took you " + counter + " tries.");  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        answerLabel.setText("Yay! It took you " + counter + " try."); 
                    }
                }
                else //hangs up here, never changes the answerLabel
                { //I believe I need to clear userInput or something of that nature
                    answerLabel.setText("Incorrect. Please try again.");
                    counter ++;
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                answerLabel.setText("Integers only please!");
                correctInput = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : The errors it gives me when I use InputMismatch is :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at guiapp.MathTutor$CustomActionListener.actionPerformed(GUIApp.java:167)
at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6302)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're catching the NFE just fine, but you're still caught in your `while` loop. In this way, you'll just throw infinite exceptions because you're setting `correctInput` to false, which continues the loop.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I need to fix my loop. EDIT: If I remove the while loop it works fine. Many thanks